# Not getting the desired outcome for this ShortestPath problem in Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, graph

So I got some pointers and now I got this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at udacity.GraphPraticeKt.shortestPath(GraphPratice.kt:159)
    at udacity.GraphPraticeKt.main(GraphPratice.kt:264)
    at udacity.GraphPraticeKt.main(GraphPratice.kt)
```

The goal is to find the shortest path to the following graph

```
  val SPE = listOf(
        listOf('w', 'x'),
        listOf('x', 'y'),
        listOf('z', 'y'),
        listOf('z', 'v'),
        listOf('w', 'v')
    )
```

Here's my code that I have so far

```
fun shortestPath(edges: List<List<Char>>, root: Char, destination: Char): Any {
    val graph =  buildGraph3(edges)
    val visited = hashSetOf(root)
    val queue = mutableListOf(Pair(root, 0))

    while (queue.size > 0){
        val current = queue.removeFirst()
        val node = current.first
        val distance = current.second

        if (node == destination) return distance

        graph[node]!!.forEach{
            if (!visited.contains(it)){
                visited.add(it)
                queue.add(Pair(node, distance + 1))
            }

        }


    }
    queue.sortedByDescending { it.second }

    return println(queue[0].second)
}

fun buildGraph3(edges: List<List<Char>>): HashMap<Char, MutableList<Char>> {
    val graph = HashMap<Char, MutableList<Char>>()

    for (i in edges.indices){
        for (n in 0 until edges[i].size){
            var a = edges[i][0]
            var b = edges[i][1]
            if (!graph.containsKey(a)) { graph[a] = mutableListOf() }
            if (!graph.containsKey(b)) { graph[b] = mutableListOf() }
            graph[a]?.add(b)
            graph[b]?.add(a)
        }
    }
    return graph
}
```

If I was to put w and z as the root and destination, I should get 2. Any help or tips is welcomed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was minor things that needed to be changed.

1. The return type had from `Any` to change to `Int`. I had it at `Any` so that I could print the output with the function, but it's not necessary and it's actually better to do it that way.
2. I didn't realize I put `node` instead of `it` inside the forEach loop. That was causing the error
3. I took off the `queue.sortedByDescending { it.second }` because I realized that the queue was already in that order. so no need to add a sorting algorithm to it.

Here's the correct code

```
fun shortestPath(edges: List<List<Char>>, root: Char, destination: Char): Int {
    val graph =  buildGraph3(edges)
    val visited = hashSetOf(root)
    val queue = mutableListOf(Pair(root, 0))


    while (queue.isNotEmpty()){
        val current = queue.removeFirst()
        val node = current.first
        val distance = current.second

        if (node == destination) return distance

        graph[node]!!.forEach{
            if (!visited.contains(it)){
                visited.add(it)
                queue.add(Pair(it, distance + 1))
            }

        }


    }

    return queue[0].second
}

fun buildGraph3(edges: List<List<Char>>): HashMap<Char, MutableList<Char>> {
    val graph = HashMap<Char, MutableList<Char>>()

    for (i in edges.indices){
        for (n in 0 until edges[i].size){
            val a = edges[i][0]
            val b = edges[i][1]
            if (!graph.containsKey(a)) { graph[a] = mutableListOf() }
            if (!graph.containsKey(b)) { graph[b] = mutableListOf() }
            graph[a]?.add(b)
            graph[b]?.add(a)
        }
    }
    return graph
}
```